# C# trying to override ShowDialog()

Tags: c#

I am very weak in overriding, overloading etc. so I couldn't handle this. My problem is this,

I have a frmDialog. It is only used to show the process messages, error messages etc. It takes its text from log, so I don't need to pass a variable to it. After each process(on other forms), I create this form and call ofrmDialog.ShowDialog(). My problem is that, even when the text is empty, this dialog box opens and shows nothing. So I wanted to override this ShowDialog. ShowDialog returns DialogResult, so I really can't figure out how to do this.

```
public override DialogResult ShowDialog(){
    if(this.Text != string.Empty){
    return base.ShowDialog();
    }
    else{
    //don't do anything
    }
}
```

What do I return when there is else? I really can't understand this.

Comment: well... if there isn't a value, do you consider that to be "OK", "Cancel", ...? But I agree with GeorgePotter that *avoiding* the `ShowDialog` is a better option.

Comment: nothing. I don't want that dialog box to open.

Comment: then why are you calling `ShowDialog`... you know, the method *intended to open a form*? But that is besides the point: `ShowDialog` *must* return something: it is required to. Callers can *catch* this value, to see what the result was. You *must* consider that scenario to be one of "ok", "cancel", "retry" etc... (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx)

Comment: maybe writing another method, such as myShow() and maybe use the base ShowDialog in it, else return something else? I tried that too but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Put it like this, when ShowDialog is called normally, what does it return? Does is return an OK or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I'd recommend putting the ShowDialog in an if statement so that it's only triggered if the text isn't empty.

e.g.

```
if(text is not empty)
{
    //Show dialog
}
```

That way you can avoid the issues you're currently having. If you have to return something you can set DialogResult to equal what it needs to be - OK or Cancel for example.

Based on your comments however, I suggest you put this in the else statement of your code:

```
else
{
    return base.ShowDialog = "<OK>";
}
```

Comment: I know it is the cleanest but I don't think my supervisors would let me change all of them. That is the reason I am trying to override the ShowDialog()

Comment: Ah, is this something which comes up multiple times in the code? In that case then just don't include the Else statement - you don't have to have it for the code to work if I recall correctly.

Comment: It would still need to return *something*.

Comment: Hmm. What kind of DialogResult is needed? Because you could just set it to equal "<cancel>" or "<ok>"

Comment: When there is text, the dialog box should open, but when there is not, they don't want to see an empty dialog box with just an "OK" button it and no text. That is what I am trying to do but well, I can't

Comment: There is no "null" dialogbox, so I think I won't be able to do it on the frmDialog form. I should check the text 860 times.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But from what you're saying it sounds like that if the text contains something then you show that in a dialog box and the user clicks OK. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. But now it shows it anyways. Without checking the text. So a dialog box always opens with an OK button

Comment: Okay, I've just edited the answer - try what I recommended and see if it works.

Comment: I am doing many things wrong. Now I am getting " cannot override inherited member  because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override " I think I will give up

Comment: when I override it with new, it doesn't enter the form_load, so the this.Text is empty and base never shows the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than overriding ShowDialog, you need something higher up so that the frmDialog is only constructed and shown if there is some text to display.

```
public DialogResult ShowMessage(string text)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        FrmDialog frmDialog = new FrmDialog(text);
        dialogResult = frmDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
    return dialogResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

else{
    return DialogResult.OK;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends if any of the callers check the dialog result, you've stated in a comment that you have 860 calls to this method do any of them check the result? If not it doesn't really matter yet what it returns, it only matters in the future to avoid a WTF?! when you're non-showing dialog returns OK.

Since you have to return something maybe `DialogResult.None` would be the least confusing later